# JpGraph : no error but broken picture

Tags: php, jpgraph

I make a graph with JPGraph but I've a little problem.

No error was displayed but the picture is a "broken picture".

Here is my code :

```
$graph = new Graph(1000,300);
$graph->img->SetMargin(40,30,50,40);    
$graph->SetScale("textlin");
$graph->title->Set("Graph");

$graph->ygrid->Show();
$graph->ygrid->SetColor('blue@0.7');
$graph->ygrid->SetLineStyle('dashed');

$graph->xgrid->Show();
$graph->xgrid->SetColor('red@0.7');
$graph->xgrid->SetLineStyle('dashed');

$graph->title->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_BOLD,11);

$bigCourbe = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($bigData as $data)
{
    var_dump($data);

    $courbe = new LinePlot($data);
    $courbe->value->Show();

    $courbe->value->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_NORMAL,9);
    $courbe->value->SetFormat('%d');

    $courbe->mark->SetType(MARK_FILLEDCIRCLE);
    $courbe->mark->SetFillColor("green");
    $courbe->mark->SetWidth(2);

    $courbe->SetWeight(10);         

    echo $function[$i];
    $courbe->SetLegend($function[$i++]);

    $bigCourbe[] = $courbe;
}

$graph->xaxis->title->Set("Heures");
$graph->yaxis->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);
$graph->xaxis->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);

foreach ($bigCourbe as $elem) {
        $graph->Add($elem);
}

//$graph->Stroke();
```

So, the result seems good :

```
array (size=24)
0 => string '0.000' (length=5)
1 => string '0.000' (length=5)
2 => string '0.000' (length=5)
3 => string '0.000' (length=5)
4 => string '0.000' (length=5)
5 => string '0.000' (length=5)
....
Index HC <- it's the $function[$i] var

array (size=24)
0 => string '0.200' (length=5)
1 => string '0.200' (length=5)
2 => string '0.100' (length=5)
3 => string '0.200' (length=5)
4 => string '0.200' (length=5)
5 => string '0.200' (length=5)
....
Index HP

array (size=24)
0 => string '0.000' (length=5)
1 => string '0.000' (length=5)
2 => string '0.000' (length=5)
3 => string '0.000' (length=5)
4 => string '0.000' (length=5)
5 => string '0.000' (length=5)
Index HPTE

array (size=24)
0 => string '0.200' (length=5)
1 => string '0.200' (length=5)
2 => string '0.100' (length=5)
3 => string '0.200' (length=5)
4 => string '0.200' (length=5)
5 => string '0.200' (length=5)
....
Total Heure
```

I do not see the problem...

If I remove the debug, and uncomment the $graph->Stroke(); line. I have that :

[image]

Can you help me ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: make sure all the fonts are available..

Comment: All the fonts are available. It's not that :(

Comment: What if you set PHP to print all errors?

Comment: PHP already print all errors :(

Answer (score 2):

in my case (php 7.1.0) it was Deprecated message

just put

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

at the top of your script and try again.

or

comment out `$graph->Stroke();` and see what error(or warning) you have

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I just had the same problem and fixed it by removing everything before the `<?php`.

THis was suggested in the link below - check 1.b.

[Solution Source](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch03s07.html)

Answer (score 0):

How do you display the graph? Do you have an HTML page? Please show the HTML code.
I have a similar problem where I have no error message, but get the broken image icon.

[jpGraph can't include PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530582/jpgraph-cant-include-php-file)

One thing I would recommend is to add the lines

```
//save to file
$fileName = "/tmp/imagefile.png";
$graph->img->Stream($fileName);
```

if the image from the file is correct, then you can rule out the graph generating code.