# jpGraph can't include PHP file

Tags: php, html, jpgraph

I am trying to include one PHP file in another PHP file that creates a jpGraph image

(The reason is that I am loading mySQL data for the chart, and I want to put the login credentials into a separate file)

I know that the chart is created (because a correct image file is created) but the chart does not show up in the web page.

Here is a simplified code example:

login.inc.php

```
  <?php
  $lhostname="localhost";
  $lusername="joeschmack";
  $lpassword="autumnleaf";
  $ldatabase="customers";
  ?>
```

accbarex1.html

```
<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>This is where I want to display my graph</h3>
    <img src="accbarex1.php">
  </body>
</html>
```

accbarex1.php

```
<?php // content="text/plain; charset=utf-8"

require_once ('../../../lib/jpgraph/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('../../../lib/jpgraph/jpgraph_bar.php');
include("./login.inc.php");


$data1y=array(-8,8,9,3,5,6);
$data2y=array(18,2,1,7,5,4);

// Create the graph. These two calls are always required
$graph = new Graph(500,400); 
$graph->SetScale("textlin");

$graph->SetShadow();
$graph->img->SetMargin(40,30,20,40);

// Create the bar plots
$b1plot = new BarPlot($data1y);
$b1plot->SetFillColor("orange");
$b1plot->value->Show();
$b2plot = new BarPlot($data2y);
$b2plot->SetFillColor("blue");
$b2plot->value->Show();

// Create the grouped bar plot
$gbplot = new AccBarPlot(array($b1plot,$b2plot));

// ...and add it to the graPH
$graph->Add($gbplot);

$graph->title->Set("Accumulated bar plots");
$graph->xaxis->title->Set("X-title");
$graph->yaxis->title->Set("Y-title");

//$graph->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);
//$graph->yaxis->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);
//$graph->xaxis->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);

// Display the graph
$graph->Stroke();

//save to file
$fileName = "/tmp/imagefile.png";
$graph->img->Stream($fileName);

?>
```

The file shows the correct chart, but the web page accbarex1.html shows a broken image.
If I comment out the line

```
include("./login.inc.php");
```

then both work.

Why? And how can I include a file in this situation?

**Edit** 5-13-2013:

Given that the include line is active.
This helps (both file and embedded chart work)

- ./login.inc.php does not exist
- ./login.inc.php is empty

This does not help (only file works, embedded chart does not work)

- use absolute path for include file
- ./login.inc.php contains the line
  bla    // PHP error
- ./login.inc.php contains the line $i=1;  // no PHP error, no PHP tags

**Edit** 5-14-2013:

Some slight progress: Firefox shows the same behavior, but at least I get an error message. Error console says:

Image corrupt or truncated: http:// .. acbarex1.php

Comment: Check your error logs and try using an absolute link (/home/user/public_html/login.inc.php) instead of a relative one.

Comment: To troubleshoot this problem, comment out the last line (`$graph->img->Stream($fileName);`) and execute accbarex1.php directly to see what output is being produced by `include("./login.inc.php")` or other parts of the script.

Comment: Absolute path: no change.

Comment: Absolute path: no change. 
While experimenting, I noticed: If I include a file that does not exist, the chart works. So it is something about including the file. 
If I include 
<?php
$i=1;
?> 
same result-no improvement.
If I include an empty file, the chart works. Perhaps something about including the PHP tags <?php   ..      ?>
Perhaps it doesn't like nested PHP tags?

Where do I find the error logs?
Thanks

Comment: Apache error log: no error, no warning.. (sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log) Browser debugging: no error, no warning. (Chrome, hit CTRL-SHIFT-j). All I know is that the browser shows a broken image, but the file in /tmp shows the correct chart.

Comment: After reviewing the sample jpgraph code, I realized two things: You are sending the image output (`->Stroke()`) without first setting the headers, and you are saving the image output to a file in the same script that is generating output. I recommend setting the headers according to the docs, and try commenting out the lines that write the image to a file.

Comment: Do you mean the lines require_once ('../../../lib/jpgraph/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('../../../lib/jpgraph/jpgraph_bar.php'); ? Those are already included (Did you see them? my code above has a scroll bar)

Answer (score 1):

I found what the problem was. I had extra characters after the closing ?>, but I could not see them because they were spaces and newline. These characters messed up the jpGraph image.

Before:

```
  <?php
  $lhostname="localhost";
  $lusername="joeschmack";
  $lpassword="autumnleaf";
  $ldatabase="customers";
  ?><SPACE><SPACE><NEWLINE>
```

After:

```
  <?php
  $lhostname="localhost";
  $lusername="joeschmack";
  $lpassword="autumnleaf";
  $ldatabase="customers";
  ?>
```

That fixed it! Beware the extra characters!